# Display date and time of record with grid cell data

Tags: extjs

I am using a single-cell grid to show notifications in my application. How do I show date and time of notification with each cell data? The data is present in the model of the associated store. I want it to be something like the phabricator https://secure.phabricator.com/

Any pointers how I may do so?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to use a `templatecolumn`.  You can then specify a `tpl` in the config of html representing the two sources of data.

[Here is a fiddle I created](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/kev) demonstrating and simple and more complex tpl that resembles the data on the site you referenced.

Here is a simple example of a template column:

```
                {
                    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    header:'Name',
                    tpl:'{first_name} {last_name}'
                }
```

And a more complex template column with similar style to the one you referenced:

```
                {
                    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    header: 'Example With Date',
                    flex: 1,
                    tpl:'<span style="display:inline-table;width:50%;">{first_name}</span><span style="width: 50%;display: inline-table;text-align: right;">{myDate}</span>'
                }
```